# dataframe dropping all nan index and cells keeping original index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have data like below with nan index and nan cells

```
      id  no      name        percentage  score       result
0     0   0.30    pencils     0.84        0.974185    1
1     1   0.18    computer    1.14        1.0         1
2     2   0.27    laptop      1.32        1.0         1
nan   0   0.18    apples      1.59        0.999655    4
4     1   0.84    vegetables  1.770008    0.99992     4
      id  no      name        percentage  score       result
0     0   nan     chicken     0.84        0.974185    1
1     1   0.18    fish        1.14        .           1
2     2   0.27    meat        1.32        1.0         1
```

I want to keep the original index and drop all rows where `nan index` and `nan cells` or `special character` like `.` and `without repeated header` as below

```
    id  no      name        percentage  score       result
0   0   0.30    pencils     0.84        0.974185    1
1   1   0.18    computer    1.14        1.0         1
2   2   0.27    laptop      1.32        1.0         1
4   1   0.84    vegetables  1.770008    0.99992     4
2   2   0.27    meat        1.32        1.0         1
```

I tried but, I cannot keep the original index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [394]: df
Out[394]: 
     id    no        name percentage     score  result
0     0  0.30     pencils       0.84  0.974185     1.0
1     1  0.18    computer       1.14       1.0     1.0
2     2  0.27      laptop       1.32       1.0     1.0
NaN   0  0.18      apples       1.59  0.999655     4.0
4     1  0.84  vegetables   1.770008   0.99992     4.0
id   no  name  percentage      score    result     NaN
0     0   NaN     chicken       0.84  0.974185     1.0
1     1  0.18        fish       1.14         .     1.0
2     2  0.27        meat       1.32       1.0     1.0

In [393]: df[~df.eq('.').any(1) & ~df.index.isin(df.columns) & df.index.notna()].dropna()
Out[393]: 
  id    no        name percentage     score  result
0  0  0.30     pencils       0.84  0.974185     1.0
1  1  0.18    computer       1.14       1.0     1.0
2  2  0.27      laptop       1.32       1.0     1.0
4  1  0.84  vegetables   1.770008   0.99992     4.0
2  2  0.27        meat       1.32       1.0     1.0
```